# Why does a native delete query using aliases not work in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

Is there any known issue in having alias with DELETE in JPA Spring data? The same works like a charm on removing alias.
I have a JPA Spring data native query as below:-

```
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "delete from Customer d where d.name = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    public void removeOnName(String name);
```

This throws an exception as below:-

```
    01:11:13.616 [main] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
01:11:13.616 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd where d.name = 'kiran'' at line 1
01:11:13.621 [main] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Warning Code: 1064, SQLState: 42000
01:11:13.621 [main] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd where d.name = 'kiran'' at line 1
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:172)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:155)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.removeDevciesOnGuid(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
```

The query executes fine when i remove the alias.
The working query as below:-

```
 @Modifying
        @Transactional
        @Query(value = "delete from Customer where name = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
        public void removeOnName(String name);
```

*Is there any known issue in having alias with DELETE in JPA Spring data? The same works like a charm on removing alias.*

**Reference Done**
The documentation also shows using alias http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

**From Documentation:-
2.5.1 Transactional query methods**

To allow your query methods to be transactional simply use @Transactional at the repository interface you define.

Example 2.20. Using @Transactional at query methods

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  List<User> findByLastname(String lastname);

      @Modifying
  @Transactional
  @Query("delete from User u where u.active = false")
  void deleteInactiveUsers();
}
```

Typically you will want the readOnly flag set to true as most of the query methods will only read data. In contrast to that deleteInactiveUsers() makes use of the @Modifying annotation and overrides the transaction configuration. Thus the method will be executed with readOnly flag set to false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set `nativeQuery`  flag of `@Query`  to true, so query sent to the server (in your case Mysql) as it is. Mysql doesn't allow aliases in `DELETE`. Set `nativeQuery` to false or don't use aliases.

*Surely, there is also an option to use , for instance , SQLServer which would accept such syntax instead of Mysql :)

Answer (score 0):

Reason you get an error while executing the below query is because it's not a correct MySql syntax for the delete query. You are using nativeQuery and alias usage is incorrect.

Correct syntax is:

```
"delete d from Customer as d where d.name=?1"

@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "delete d from Customer as d where d.name=?1", nativeQuery = true)
public void removeOnName(String name);
```